# Sort posts by number of matched terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, search, sort

I have form where I list all terms associated with posts as check boxes, user should pick few of them, hit search and get all posts that match all chosen terms. It works great when there are posts that match search criteria. My question is how do I display posts that have just few of matched terms and how to sort results based on number of matches. Any help is much appreciated. Thanx.

So this is the form inside search page:

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/build_search.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<?php $terms = get_terms( 'my_tax' );
$checkboxes = '';
foreach($terms as $term) :
    $checkboxes .='<input type="checkbox" name="term[]" value="'.$term -> slug.'" id="term-'.$term->term_id.'" /><label for="term-'.$term->term_id.'">'.$term->name.'</label>';
endforeach;
print $checkboxes;
?>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
```

This is what I put in build_search.php file

```
if (isset($_POST["term"])){ $terms_array = array(); $terms_array = $_POST["term"]; foreach ($terms_array as $key => $value) { $string .= $value.'+'; } $terms_string = substr($string, 0, -1); $term = $terms_string; } else { $term = ""; } $url = header("Location:/?my_tax=$term");
```

after that I have only taxonomy-my_tax.php with regular loop in it.

Comment: whats your search query/filter like?

Comment: Search output this to (Location:/?my_tax=cat1+cat2+cat3+cat4) After that it is displayed by taxonomy-my_tax.php. I need a way to show all posts from cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4 and order them depending on how much categories matched.

Comment: Are you sure that your search results are displayed by taxonomy-my_tax.php?

Comment: Yes, and everything works fine, I get posts that match ALL the terms, now I need to get all posts that match ANY of the terms and to order them by number of matched terms

Answer (score 1):

Well the only way i can think of is to create an two dimentions array of the results you want to output, and the number of matching tags.

so for example:

```
$results = array();
$searched_tags = $_post['my_tax'];
$searched_tags = explode("+", $searched_tags);
while (have_posts()){
    $the_post();
    $result['r'] = '<div class="post">
    <div class="title"><h2><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" title="'.get_the_title($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</a></h2></div>
    <div class="excerpt">'.get_the_excerpt().'</div>
    </div>';
    //get current posts terms of the taxonomy
    $current_post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'my_tax', array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'names'));
    $matchs = 0;
    //check and count matchs
    foreach ($current_post_terms as $t){
        if (in_array($t,$searched_tags){
            $matchs = $matchs + 1;
        }
    }
    $result['m'] = $matchs;
    //save results to array
    $results[] = $result;
}
//then sort array by matchs count
//quick sorting function
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['m'] == $b['m']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['m'] > $b['m']) ? -1 : 1;
}
//the actuall array sort
uasort($results, 'cmp');
foreach ($results as $result){
    echo $result['r'];
}
```

this is untested so try and report back.

Comment: Thanx for reply,
there was an error in
`//check and count matchs
    foreach ($current_post_terms as $t){
        if (in_array($t,$searched_tags){
            $matchs = $matchs + 1;
        }
    }
    $result['m'] = $matchs;`
I corrected it but it still doesn't work, I should put this code inside the taxonomy-my_tax.php right?

Comment: Its an example!!! I'd have to see the full code of the search form and taxonomy file to know better

Comment: Sorry, I should add code from the start.

Comment: seeing your code i think i know whats the problem, change `$searched_tags = $_post['my_tax'];` to `$searched_tags = $_GET['my_tax'];` and yes the whole code needs to go in your  
taxonomy-my_tax.php

Comment: Yes that was it, now I get the selected terms when I echo $searched_tags but then it breaks on while loop.

Comment: On the loop or on the sort function?

Comment: On the loop, if I omit the sorting function it still doesn't work. Thanx for all the effort, by the way :-).

Comment: Then i need to see the exact code you are using,  create a pastebin or paiste.

Comment: Ok, here it is http://pastie.org/1802144

Comment: It doesn't even go in to the loop since you already do the loop using `<?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'taxonomy' ); ?>`  so either remove that or add ` rewind_posts();` just before the loop, and report back.

Comment: Tried that already, without `get_template_part( 'loop', 'taxonomy' );` and with `php rewind_posts();` with no luck :-(

Comment: try this http://pastie.org/1802317 in your taxonomy-my_tax.php .

Comment: You mean without using `<?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'taxonomy' ); ?>`? Tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: doesn't work??? what happens i need a bit more then that , i'm really getting tired of guessing and i do want to help you

Comment: I get everything before `while (have_posts()){` so `<?php 
$results = array();
$searched_tags = $_GET['my_tax'];
$searched_tags = explode("+", $searched_tags);
foreach($searched_tags as $value){
echo $value;
}` is executed and selected terms are there but nothing more, it just breaks on `while (have_posts()){...`

Comment: breaks means what? also try to add `the_title();` somewhere inside the loop to see if it runs.

Comment: I will put this online tomorrow so you can see how it breaks, thank You very much for helping.

Comment: This is the example http://pro.ba/enes/wp/?my_tax=cat1+cat2+cat3+cat4 there is this code http://pastie.org/1802317 inside taxonomy-my_tax.php

Comment: try adding var_dump($results); before and after `uasort($results, 'cmp');` and tell me what you get.

Comment: ok, did it but nothing http://pro.ba/enes/wp/?my_tax=cat1+cat2+cat3+cat4, it also doesn't output anything if I put just `while (have_posts()){
    $the_post();
    $result['r'] = '<div class="post">
    <div class="title"><h2><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" title="'.get_the_title($post->ID).'">'.get_the_title($post->ID).'</a></h2></div>
    <div class="excerpt">'.get_the_excerpt().'</div>
    </div>';
    echo $result['r'];
}
` so I guess problem is somewhere there

Comment: ok that means it's not finding any posts, good we are getting somewhere, now add `global $query_string; echo $query_string;`
and tell me what you get

Comment: I got my_tax=cat1%2Bcat2.

Comment: You can see it on the http://pro.ba/enes/wp/?my_tax=cat1+cat2+cat3+cat4 , I upload every change

Comment: ok, getting progress, try this code:
http://pastie.org/1803677

Comment: this is that code http://pro.ba/enes/wp/?my_tax=cat1+cat2+cat3 with `var_dump($args);` after `query_posts($args);`

Comment: it makes no sence!!! it outputs `$searched_tags` as a string instead of an array, pu this code exactly http://pastie.org/1803677 and let me see

Comment: Ok, i did it, please check.

Comment: ok we see sidebar now :) try this code http://pastie.org/1803677 its updated to output the vars

Comment: Updated, please check.

Comment: Do you want me to give you access to admin area, these comments are starting to look like chat :)? is this allowed on stackexchange?

Comment: its still not finding any posts , lets check the get var, try this code. http://pastie.org/1803677

Comment: Pasted, please check.

Comment: googd updated your code with http://pastie.org/1803677

Comment: Updated, please check.

Comment: ok using this code exactly i get results http://pastie.org/1803677

Comment: Hm, pasted your code, but don't get anything, please look.

Comment: give me a few hours i'll write you a search from scratch.

Comment: _these comments are starting to look like chat :)? is this allowed on stackexchange?_ Site had flagged this thread for moderator attention. So I guess you should take a hint and use chat (we have chat, nice one) or something for such overly extended discussions in the future. :)